# How can I prevent IE from using my windows identity when accessing local websites?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

I'm doing some tests on a Windows Server 2008.

When I try to access an URL (for example the TFS webservice URL) for test purposes, it automatically uses my Windows identity (ie Administrator)

How can I force IE to display the login popup so that I can try to log in with a "standard" user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Control Panel - Internet Properties - Security Settings - User Authentication - Logon - Prompt for username and password